# Preallocate Memory for list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, memory-management, lapply

I am performing an analysis of our product performance in R. For each product we are returning a list which includes several summary statistics of the results. This is all being done in a lapply() loop. The most expensive operation in this whole process is actually the memory allocation for the list to store the results of the analysis. Is there a way to pre-allocate the memory for a list of lists? I have seen it done for vectors and matrices but not for a list of lists.

Example of Current Code:

```
# Merely to generate example product names
product_names <- as.vector(
  outer(outer(LETTERS[seq(1, 26, 1)], LETTERS[seq(1, 26, 1)], paste, sep=""),
        LETTERS[seq(1, 26, 1)], paste, sep = ""
  )
)

model_result <- lapply(product_names, function(product_name){
  # Do analysis here
  # The actual code takes data from a data.table and performs the analysis
  # This code is provided to illustrate what is being returned
  result1 <- 0.0
  result2 <- 1.0
  # Vector of results can have variable length although type is known
  # ahead of time
  vectorResult1 <- runif(sample(1:30, 1), 1, 10)
  vectorResult2 <- runif(sample(1:30, 1), 1, 10)

  product_result <- list(
    result1 = result1,
    result2 = result2,
    vectorResult1 = vectorResult1,
    vectorResult2 = vectorResult2
  )
  return(product_result)
})
```

Using `lineprof` with the actual code shows that the instantiation of the list in the loop takes more time than everything else which is why I'm curious if there is a way to pre-allocate the lists to speed this up. Are there better approaches to returning a set of results from an analysis? The reason I have gone with a list instead of indexing into a `data.frame` or `data.table` is due to the variable length of the vector results.

I am aware that this may not be possible but I've often been surprised at what StackOverflow has been able to come up with. I do know the max length of the `vectorResult1` and `vectorResult2` vectors.

System: R 3.2.2 Windows Server Essentials 2014 64 bit.

**UPDATE 2015-10-20 2:21 PM**

I am using the following code to evaluate the timing difference in lapply versus pre-allocation. Please feel free to critique my code and methods. This was based on some early feedback which the other user decided to delete:

```
lapply_timing <- system.time({
  replicate(50,{
      model_result <- lapply(product_names, function(product_name){
      # Do analysis here
      # The actual code takes date from a data.table and performs the analysis
      # This code is provided to illustrate what is being returned
      result1 <- 0.0
      result2 <- 1.0
      # Vector of results can have variable length although type is known
      # ahead of time
      vectorResult1 <- runif(sample(1:30, 1), 1, 10)
      vectorResult2 <- runif(sample(1:30, 1), 1, 10)

      product_result <- list(
        result1 = result1,
        result2 = result2,
        vectorResult1 = vectorResult1,
        vectorResult2 = vectorResult2
      )
      return(product_result)
    })
  })
})

lapply_timing


preallocate_timing <- system.time({
  replicate(50, {
    tst <- vector("list", length(product_names)); for (i in seq_along(tst)) tst[[i]] <- vector("list", 4)

    for(i in 1:length(product_names)){
      result1 <- 0.0
      result2 <- 1.0
      # Vector of results can have variable length although type is known
      # ahead of time
      vectorResult1 <- runif(sample(1:30, 1), 1, 10)
      vectorResult2 <- runif(sample(1:30, 1), 1, 10)

      tst[[i]][[1]] <- result1
      tst[[i]][[2]] <- result2
      tst[[i]][[3]] <- vectorResult1
      tst[[i]][[4]] <- vectorResult2
    }
  })
})

preallocate_timing
```

This is showing negligible difference in performance between the two which makes me think that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The lack of difference may be due to all the other calculations dominating the timings. (There may be a lesson to be read regarding what to worry about.)

Comment: If that is the case then my example is a poor one.

Comment: Why don't you show the results of your line profiling?

Comment: The two just aren't all that different since the functions you are calling, like `lapply` do the memory allocation for you (except for `for`).  `for` is weird in R, for example you can't modify the iterator as in `for(i in 1:2) i <- 1`, or maybe thats probably normal for interpreted.

Comment: @Alex I'm not showing the lineprof results since it is coming from our internal code base for product ordering optimization. I tried constructing an example which illustrates the behavior I was observing. I was most interested in whether the memory pre-allocation was even possible or profitable. I'm leaving this question here for others to come across since I couldn't find anything which addressed my situation.

Comment: You've noted that you're doing something wrong.... Yet you're asking us to give you a correct answer based on an incorrect and incomplete description of your problem. That is a ridiculous request.

Comment: @Alex I am going with BondedDust's comment that the lack of difference illustrates that this is not something to worry about optimizing. My comment about 'doing something wrong' was an self deprecating comment about my gut telling me that this should be performing faster. I am obviously incorrect and my worrying about pre-allocating a list of lists is unfounded. I was putting this up here in case someone with superior understanding of R's internals could correct my methods or perceptions. Thank you for your help. It was not my intention to pose a ridiculous request.

Comment: @Alex If someone answered by saying, "You can't optimize that and here's why..." I would mark that as the correct answer since that appears to be the case. I always appreciate StackOverflow questions where the answer is, "No, don't do that and here is why..." I believe this may be such a case.